# Can anyone tell me what "node" is being referred to here & how is the sample test case even working? What is the exact meaning of edges in the array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

Write a program that does the following: Accept the following inputs: (1) Number of nodes (2) A 2-D array representing edges. ith edge connects node input2[0][i] to node input2[1][i]. Assuming that a line can be drawn between nodes if there is an edge between them, print number of lines that can be drawn between nodes.

Sample test case:
input1: 4
input2: {{1,1,1},{2,3,4}}
output1: 3

Comment: Did you find the exact solution for this? Can you share.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a way to represent a directed graph. The number of nodes implies a set of nodes number from `1` to `input1`. `input2` then appears to be a two-element list. Each element of `input2[0]` represents the starting point of an edge, and each corresponding element of `input2[1]` represents the end point. In your example, there are 4 nodes (1, 2, 3, 4), with edges connecting node 1 to each of nodes 2, 3, and 4.

```
                      * 4
                      ^
                      |
                      |
                      | 
                    1 * --------> * 2
                      |
                      |
                      |
                      v
                      * 3
```

The output is 3 because the contents of `input2` represents the three edges shown in the diagram.

Comment: I understand a little bit. But can you explain me with a different sample case like taking nodes and input by yourself and the output as well??

Comment: `input1` is just the number of `*` in the diagram. If `input1 == 10`, there would be 10 `*`, numbered 1 to 10. `input2` should consist of exactly 2 lists, regardless of the value of `input1`. Each of those sublists should have the same length, which is not related to `input1`, but each number in the sublists should be a value between `1` and `input1`. The pair `(input2[0][i], input2[1][i])` just tells you where to draw the lines.

Comment: I've understand completely. Just 1 question, let's just say I've have 5 nodes and my list is [[1,2,3] , [2,1,3]]. So if I'm not wrong I can draw 6 lines i.e.
input1: 5
input2: [[1,2,3] , [2,1,3]]
Output: 6

Comment: That's a question for your instructor; is each pair a single directed edge, or a pair of edges (one in each direction)?